# Error C1017 for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I was building VTK on Visual Studio 2010 by following the steps at this link: http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/common/howto/winVTK.html

But I'm receving "error C1017: invalid integer constant expression" for hundreds of times and one MSB6006.

Example error:

```
#if VTK_SIZEOF_FLOAT == 4 typedef float vtkTypeFloat32; 
# define VTK_TYPE_FLOAT32 VTK_FLOAT 
#else 
# error "No native data type can represent a 32-bit floating point value." 
#endif
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Perhaps the code/compilation options violated the rules stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5sh3k99(v=vs.100).aspx, i.e. "The expression in an #if directive did not exist or did not evaluate to a constant."

Comment: Thanks. but how and where can I change the expression given at that link?

Comment: I'd start by looking at a few of the errors (by clicking on the build error) and see if that is indeed the problem. If it is, perhaps you should post some of the offending code. Unfortunately, I don't use visual c++ on a daily basis so I can't help you beyond that, but I'm sure someone else can.

Comment: Thank you. You are very helpful. But I'm not sure I understood you perfectly. I'm building VTK library on Visual Studio 2010. I do not know where the code you're talking about is. You have any clue?

Comment: I assume you downloaded the source and are building it...any build errors should be linked to the file/line which is causing the error. If you go to one of the errors, you can see if a non-integer value is `#defined`.

Comment: You were right. There's an error here: #if VTK_SIZEOF_FLOAT == 4
typedef float vtkTypeFloat32;
# define VTK_TYPE_FLOAT32 VTK_FLOAT
#else
# error "No native data type can represent a 32-bit floating point value."
#endif   You have any idea to fix this?

Comment: So then `VTK_SIZEOF_FLOAT` is either undefined or doesn't evaluate to a constant. I've added the error and the c++ tag to your question so someone can help you further.